# python3 wx.media video and image show?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, wx.media
import time

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self,
                                            szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10,
                                            style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,)

        self.MOVE = ('6.mpg', '7.wmv','1.avi','4.jpg')
        self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[0])
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play, self.testMedia)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STATECHANGED, self.play2, self.testMedia)

    def play(self, e):
        self.testMedia.GetBestSize()
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def play2(self, e): 
        if self.testMedia.GetState() == wx.media.MEDIASTATE_STOPPED:
            for i in range(len(self.MOVE)):
                if i == 1:
                    self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[1])
                elif i == 2:
                    self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[2])
                elif i == 3:
                    self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[3])                   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Fream = TestPanel()
    Fream.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

help me plz how next self.MOVE[0] -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [0] .... Loop play 
I’m at a loss what to do next... and Where can see wx.media tutorial and exmple code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STATECHANGED it could change for other reasons than the media has finished. Use wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED instead.
You can loop using a simple counter.
On state Finished perform the next Load with the index and the code should work.
I note that the last item you load is a .jpg. Not sure how that is meant to "finish"!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, wx.media
import time

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self,
                                            szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10,
#                                            szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER,
                                            style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,)

        self.MOVE = ('6.mpg', '7.wmv','1.avi','4.jpg')
#        self.MOVE = ('V1.mp4', 'V2.mp4','V3.mp4','V4.mp4')
        self.Mrange = 0
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play, self.testMedia)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.play2, self.testMedia)
        self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[self.Mrange])

    def play(self, e):
        print "Playing:",self.MOVE[self.Mrange]
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def play2(self, e): 
        self.testMedia.Stop()
        self.Mrange += 1
        print self.Mrange
        if self.Mrange > len(self.MOVE) -1:
            self.Mrange = 0
        self.testMedia.Load(self.MOVE[self.Mrange])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Fream = TestPanel()
    Fream.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello I have a question. (Jpg, png, bmp) files go faster than windows environment when I play it repeatedly on Linux. Can not adjust this? (Can not adjust to the desired time?)

Comment: As far as I know wx.media is designed to play videos and audio not images. As soon as you have loaded and displayed an image, essentially, it has finished. The simplest way I can think of to display them for a period of time, would be to test for an image file and use a simple `time.sleep()` within the loop when one is found. Place the test and sleep after `self.testMedia.Play()`